# Scope of protected members

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Iam preparing for SCJP , also i came to know that protected members scope is within the package as well as in other package with some conditions like possible only with inheritance.

For example :
i have three classes as Parentclass Childclass Friendclass

```
package x.parent;

 class Parentclass{
 protected int x=10;
  ...............
  }

 package x.child;

 class Childlass extends Parentclass{
  super.x=20;
  ...............
}

 package x.child;

 import x.parent.Parentclass;

 class Friendclass{
 Parentclass pc = new Parentclass();
 pc.x=30;
  ...............
}
```

Whats the reason behind that, in Friendclass the member x will not accept to assign a value to that, behaves as private member not in case of Childclass.

Comment: The assignment `x=20` in Childclass should also fail because it's in another package and member `x` is not `protected` but with default access.

Comment: sorry mistake from my side too. corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't even access `Parentclass.x` in `Childclass` because `x` has default visibility (not protected). See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

edit:

`x.child.Friendclass` is **not in the same package** as `x.parent.Parentclass`.
`x.child.Friendclass` **does not inherit** from `x.parent.Parentclass`.

as TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars's summary states and the Java access control docs also state, this means that `Friendclass` is not allowed to access the field `x`.

Comment: i have edited the question yesterday, please can you check once

Comment: Answer also edited to reflect your changes. I hope it's absolutely clear now.

Answer (score 10):

There are four access modifiers

```
private - just this class
no modifier - just this class or this package (NOT subclass)
protected - just this class, this package, or subclass
public - everyone and their cousin
```

Since it uses the default modifier, it has access if one of the following is true:

1. Is part of the class itself (Nope!)
2. Is part of the package of the class itself (Nope!)

So it fails the criteria, and so you don't get access.

Comment: you are wrong , protected members can be accessed by using inheritance in another package

Comment: Flipped definitions for "protected" and "no modifier", no?

Comment: @Damodar, zerocrates - yep I flipped 'em. Fixed.

Comment: i have edited the question yesterday, please can you check once